# Show total expense in each category for last SIX months in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**PLEASE READ THIS BEFORE MARKING AS DUPLICATE**

This is the structure of products table:
[image: Table products]

There are more than 600 Rows of record in this table.

What I want is that it shows something like this

```
| Category | Price | Month | Year  |
|  Bills   | 12389 |  08   | 2017  |
|  Food    | 10589 |  08   | 2017  |
|  ...     | ..... |  ..   | ....  |
|  Bills   | 18989 |  07   | 2017  |
|  Food    | 20589 |  07   | 2017  |
|  ...     | ..... |  ..   | ....  |
|  Bills   | 12784 |  06   | 2017  |
|  Food    | 23589 |  06   | 2017  |
|  ...     | ..... |  ..   | ....  |
```

What I did ?

```
SELECT category AS 'Category', SUM(total_PRICE) AS 'Total Amount' 
FROM `products`
WHERE month(DATE)=(SELECT MONTH(CURDATE())) AND year(DATE)=(SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())) GROUP BY category  ORDER BY `Total Amount`  DESC
```

This one returns record for current month "**Category View**"

I also tried this one

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE date_format(date,'%Y-%m') < date_format(now(),'%Y-%m') and
      date_format(date,'%Y-%m') >= date_format(now() - interval 6 month,'%Y-%m')
```

This returns all record from last SIX months

***If it is impossible to write this type of query, then help me writing a program in PHP that will print this type of data to screen***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT category, date_format(date,'%Y-%m') as yyyymm, SUM(total_PRICE)
FROM products
WHERE date_format(date,'%Y-%m') < date_format(now(),'%Y-%m') and
      date_format(date,'%Y-%m') >= date_format(now() - interval 6 month,'%Y-%m')
GROUP BY category, date_format(date,'%Y-%m')
ORDER BY category, yyyymm DESC;
```

Comment: It Really Helped Sir.
Thanks